# delete the memory or re-upload a program

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-pro-mini

At the moment I am following the instructions of this project https://github.com/JoernL/LimiTTer. Besides the peripheral parts like a Bluetooth module and an NFC module, the central unit is an Arduino Pro Mini.
I am a bloody novice with Arduino and just taught myself how to solder stuff. So far, I successfully uploaded the program from the project above to the Arduino Mini Pro and will continue as soon as the other parts arrive.

Anyhow, since I am strictly following the instructions I have some serious knowledge gaps and hope you can help me out. So, for instance.

- How do I know, how much storage capacity is available on the Arduino board before and after I uploaded something?
- How can I delete a program from the Arduino board?
- When I upload a program, will the program that is already on the Arduino been overwritten?
- Is an Arduino generally used to execute one specific program and not to hold a set of totally different programs?

Comment: The arduino work like the way you think it does regarding-when a new program is uploaded - it replaces or deletes the previous one when uploaded. This is because the arduino is a general stored program computer -though it doesnt hold a set of programs in memory just the last one that was uploaded last. You may need to clear the EEPROM with code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I know, how much storage capacity is available on the Arduino board before and after I uploaded something?

In yellow is how much bytes does your program take.

In purple is how much bytes are available on your board.

In green is how many bytes does your **global** variables take.

In orange is how many bytes are left for **local** variables.

In blue is how many bytes are available for **all** of your variables.

In red is the general specs of your board and to which COM port it is connected to.

[image]

---

> How can I delete a program from the Arduino board?

Once  a new program is uploaded, the old one is deleted (somewhat). Still, you get all your bytes back and it is like if you start from scratch

---

> When I upload a program, will the program that is already on the Arduino been overwritten?

Yes.

---

> Is an Arduino generally used to execute one specific program and not to hold a set of totally different programs?

An Arduino can only execute 1 program at the time. It doesn't usualy hold on to any other programs, but can store 1024 bytes in it's EEPROM. This lets your write in the EEPROM with a program and access that data with an other.